# Accessing appsmarket/v2/customerLicense - error "Invalid OAuth consumer key"

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

Up until recently (i.e. a few months I believe) we were able to make GET requests successfully against https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/customerLicense and https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/licenseNotification using just our Oauth2 Consumer Key and Secret.

Those requests now fail with a status of 401 and the following body:

```
{"error"=>{"code"=>401, "message"=>"Invalid OAuth consumer key", "errors"=>[{"message"=>"Invalid OAuth consumer key", "reason"=>"authError", "locationType"=>"header", "domain"=>"global", "location"=>"Authorization"}]}}
```

Here is our Ruby code that makese the licenseNotification requests

```
  def self.google_apps_licenses(since=Time.zone.now-10.years)
    oauth_consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(GOOGLE_APPS_MARKETPLACE_CONSUMER_KEY_V2, GOOGLE_APPS_MARKETPLACE_CONSUMER_SECRET_V2)
    access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.new(oauth_consumer)
    response = access_token.get("https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/licenseNotification/#{GOOGLE_APPS_MARKETPLACE_APPLICATION_ID_V2}?timestamp=#{(since.to_i * 1000)}")
    result = JSON.parse(response.body)
  end
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Do we need to sign it now with our cert or use a JWT assertion?  It's strange that this worked at one point and then stopped.

Comment: I think consumer Key and Secret were used with Oauth 1.0 which is deprecated and stopped working on April 20, 2015. You have to use Oauth 2.0.  https://support.google.com/a/answer/162105?hl=en

Comment: Hi @gerado Thank you for the response!  Possible dumb question: how does an application make an Oauth2 request that isn't on behalf of a user?

Comment: To authorize users you can use the normal Oauth 2 flow. You will have to create credentials and with those credentials you can authenticate a user. Check the documentation on that: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2  and also check the Oauth Playground where you can see the flow step by step: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Answer (score 0):

With help from Google, I found the answer to this question.

First off, the scope for those APIs is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appsmarketplace.license (that's currently hard to find in the docs) .

Knowing that, there are two ways to generate an access_token for that scope.

1) You can send a "project member" of the App through the standard Oauth flow authorizing that scope.  You could then stash the refresh_token and use it to generate an access_token whenever you need to make a request.  However refresh_tokens can be revoked.

2) So, the preferable method is to use a Service account to generate an access_token on behalf of itself (not a user). To do that, you simply have to leave off the "sub" field in the JWT claim set that you send https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token.

Here is the ruby code to do that:

```
def self.fetch_access_token_for_marketplace_api
    claim_set = {
      "iss" => GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
      "scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appsmarketplace.license",
      "aud" => "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
      "exp" => (Time.zone.now + 50.minutes).to_i,
      "iat" => (Time.zone.now).to_i
    }
    p12 = OpenSSL::PKCS12::new(GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SERVICE_KEY, "<OMITTED>")

    jwt = JWT.encode(claim_set, p12.key, "RS256")

    data = {
      :assertion => jwt,
      :grant_type => "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"
    }
    response = make_request(:post, "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", data)
    result = JSON.parse(response.body)

    raise ServiceTokenFailedError, "Unable to refresh google service token #{result["error"]}: #{result["error_description"]}" if result["error"]
    return result["access_token"]   
end
```